# Why doesn't this question show up in the Unanswered Questions list?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

The [Unanswered Questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list is supposed to show all questions "with no upvoted or accepted answers".

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22476/would-humans-starve-if-spiders-disappeared) only has one answer with a negative score and it has not been accepted.  So why doesn't the question show up in the Unanswered Questions list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your question.

The **skeptics.stackexchange.com** is not showing unanswered questions with negative answers.

In a blog post [Ok, now define answered](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/). It said:

> As of today, here’s how we do it:
>
> - Answered questions have at least one answer with one upvote (or
>     accepted)
> - Unanswered questions have no answers with upvotes (or accepted)

Well, apparently not on skeptics.

The system is claiming to [list](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=1&tab=mytags):

> questions with no upvoted or accepted answers.

While it is actually listing:

> **questions with no answers**

For example my question [Is "Foot Fetish" caused by cross-wiring in the brain?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22906/is-foot-fetish-caused-by-cross-wiring-in-the-brain) isn't listed though it has a -9 answer.

Comment: I just went through all 25 pages in the Unanswered Questions list, and I did find this one question that has an answer with a 0 score: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/water-swirl-according-to-hemisphere-video

Comment: Try to downvote the answer please, let's see if the problem is with downvoted answers.

Comment: I'd like to be able to remove the downvote, but I'm not sure the Unanswered Questions list will update in time for me to remove the downvote?

Comment: Try upvoting the spider's answer then. Let's wait and see if the system will show it. I have reached a limit for voting, otherwise I would have voted.

Comment: I don't think upvoting it will tell us much.  You downvote it, we'll wait and see what happens, and I'll upvote it later to cancel out your downvote.  :)

Comment: OK I just downvoted it, let's see what happens.  If it takes too long, you'll have to upvote it later.

Comment: Okay, you can even remove your downvote when we edit the answer.

Comment: Good idea.  I don't see it in the list anymore.  It's a problem with negative answers.

Comment: Just what I thought, we got the bug :)

Comment: Can you make some sort of edit, since you have enough rep to apply edits immediately, so I can remove the downvote?

Comment: Okay, you may remove the downvote.

Comment: Thanks.  I already have an [open question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247373/unanswered-question-does-not-show-up-in-unanswered-questions-list) on Meta.SE related to this, I will update it later with our findings.

Comment: Oh my dog, it seems the bug is not only on this site.